# How to calculate the speedup of MPI application?

Tags: mpi

I wish to calculate the speedup of my MPI application against the number of parallel processes/nodes.

Application mostly performs huge matrices computation in parallel. 
I can measure an elapsed time using `MPI_Wtime()`, something like this..

```
double start = MPI_Wtime();  
....
double end = MPI_Wtime();
double elapsed = end - start;
```

But how can I achieve this against the degree of parallelization ?

Comment: Your question used to say 'speedup'. 'Degree of parallelization' isn't a term. What do you mean?

Comment: @Adam In clear words, I wish to know how much time is saved if I increase number of parallel processes to perform particular task.

Comment: Your best choices are speedup, or if your problem is very specific, then simply state how much faster it is. For example "5 hours on 10 cores, 1 hour on 100 cores".

Answer (score 3):

The usual definition of speedup is time on 1 process divided by time on `p` processes.

If you wish to present the performance of your code, it's good to pick a range of `p` from 1 to the highest amount you have access to run and plot the results on a speedup vs. `p` plot.

Note that strictly speaking, speedup should compare the time on `p` processes vs the *best possible sequential code*, not just running your parallel code sequentially. This seems like a moot point, but in some areas the parallel codes are pretty awful in the sequential case. In the sparse matrix world, for example, you can find a parallel code 10-50x slower than the top sequential code.

Comment: 'time on `p` processes' means what exactly? Is it a collective time spent when executing `p` processes?